# Getting self-signed certificates to work for Jupyter notebook servers in Safari

Tags: safari, certificate, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to get Jupyter notebook server to run from a workstation (running Ubuntu 14.04).  I am following the instructions [here](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html) to set up a self-signed certificate with openssl:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

The base url that I chose was `/ipython/` in `jupyter_notebook_config.py`:

```
c.NotebookApp.base_url = '/ipython/'
```

I launch my Jupyter notebook as follows:

```
jupyter notebook --certfile=$HOME/.jupyter/cert.pem --keyfile=$HOME/.jupyter/key.pem
```

In all browsers (Safari & Chrome, on both Mac OS X and iPad), I was able to connect to https://my.server.address:8888/ipython/ and create new notebooks.

However, while I am able to connect to the kernel in Google Chrome, I am not able to do so in Safari on Mac OS X.  I am getting a "Connecting to kernel" message in the Jupyter window that is permanently on.  On iPad, for both Safari & Google Chrome, I was able to access the address, create new notebooks, but everything stalls at the "Connecting to kernel" message.  The only thing that works at the moment is Google Chrome on Mac (Safari on Mac does not work and both Safari & Google Chrome on iPad do not work).

I believe the reason for this could be that Safari does not accept self-signed certificates.  I have tried [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) but for that, I need a domain name (this Jupyter notebook is running inside an intranet).

So my question is, is it possible to get Safari to accept self-signed certificates, or is there any workaround?  Is it possible to get these accepted on Safari on an iPad/iPhone as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible! Please, follow [this step-by-step guide](https://juno.sh/ssl-self-signed-cert/) to access Jupyter Notebook server on iOS via SSL using a self-signed cert.

The key here is to issue a certificate for CA and install *that* certificate on the device. Furthermore, starting with iOS 10.3 full trust is not automatically enabled for installed certificates, so pay attention to the last step.

Finally, you may want to consider using [Juno Connect](https://juno.sh/junoconnect) instead of Safari to access your notebook server — you will still need to configure certificates though, so same tutorial applies.